# Renaming a JSON key in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to process some logs and post the log contents to an API for further processing. Before I post the data to the API I need to rename the keys but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have so far.

```
import re
import json

logs = ['2016-10-13 17:04:50 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"key1": "data", "key2":"data"}',
        '2016-10-13 17:05:10 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"key1": "data", "key2":"data"}']

newLogs = []
for log in logs:
    data = (re.compile(r"Rs:({[^}]*})").search(log)).group(1))
    data.replace('key1','keyA').replace('key2','keyB')
    newLogs.append(data)


# Current output - the keys are not changed
print (newLogs)
>>>> ['2016-10-13 17:04:50 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"key1": "data", "key2":"data"}',
      '2016-10-13 17:05:10 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"key1": "data", "key2":"data"}']

#Desired output
print (newLogs)
>>>> ['2016-10-13 17:04:50 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"keyA": "data", "keyB":"data"}',
      '2016-10-13 17:05:10 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"keyA": "data", "keyB":"data"}']
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an exception? Please update the question with the error you are getting.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE].

Comment: @AKS I am trying to change key values but its not working. So there are not errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python. So the method `replace` returns a new string, which you have to capture in some variable:

```
data = data.replace('key1','keyA').replace('key2','keyB')
```

Comment: I cannot believe I made such a newbie error. I was rushing for my project so much that I completely forgot about it. This is purely a mistake on my end. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: This is fantastic, however, we cannot change the Dict and from this answer I converted Dict in to String and then renamed the key.